# How can I combine the results of multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to perform a `replace` operation on the same string with multiple threads. I have created a class that will do so, given the text and a list of string arrays containing the targets and replacements:

```
public class ParallelReplacer implements Runnable {
    private String text = "";
    private List<String[]> targetsAndReplacements = null;

    public ParallelReplacer(String text, List<String[]> targetsAndReplacements) {
        this.text = text;
        this.targetsAndReplacements = targetsAndReplacements;
        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        for(String[] s : this.targetsAndReplacements) {
            this.text = performReplace(text, s);
        }
    }

    private String performReplace(String text, String[] targetAndReplacement) {
        text = text.replace(targetAndReplacement[0], targetAndReplacement[1]);
        return text;
    }
}
```

I execute it like so:

```
List<String[]> targetsAndReplacements = new ArrayList<String[]>();
targetsAndReplacements.add(new String[] {"a", ""});
targetsAndReplacements.add(new String[] {"e", ""});
targetsAndReplacements.add(new String[] {"i", ""});
targetsAndReplacements.add(new String[] {"o", ""});
targetsAndReplacements.add(new String[] {"u", ""});

String text = "I am trying to perform a replace operation the same string with multiple threads.";
text = new ParallelReplacer(text, targetsAndReplacements.subList(0, targetsAndReplacements.size() / 2)).getResults();
text = new ParallelReplacer(text, targetsAndReplacements.subList(targetsAndReplacements.size() / 2, targetsAndReplacements.size())).getResults();
```

However, the second thread only executes after the first thread has finished, defeating the purpose of haveing multiple threads. How can I have the two threads executing simultaneously, and then merge the results after they are done?

Comment: Strings in Java are immutable, so you create a new copy of the string with each substitution anyways. This is not very condusive to "merging results".

Comment: Did you have to pick a task like this to parallelize?  If I had to choose a task that is almost impossible to process effectively and safely with more than one core, this would be a top contender:(

Comment: I hope you are just doing this task in order to play with the threading - because you won't achieve any gains in terms of perfomance. Either way most important thing is that you are doing everything in a single thread anyway as you don't create any new ones in there. Calling run method on Runnable does not create new thread.

Answer (score 1):

All your program is in the same thread

A Runnable it's a interface that need to be passed as argument of a thread

You need to execute the ParallelReplacer's instances in new threads

The question that maybe you gonna have, is how get the result, so, you want to use a callback to this, when the execution of the thread is done, the callback is called

```
public interface IMyCallback {
    public void onSucess(String result);
    public void onError();
}
```

Do this in ParallelReplacer

```
public class ParallelReplacer implements Runnable {
    //...
    IMyCallback myCallback;

    public ParallelReplacer(String text, List<String[]> targetsAndReplacements, IMyCallback myCallback) 
    {
        this.myCallback = myCallback;
        this.text = text;
        this.targetsAndReplacements = targetsAndReplacements;
        run();
    }


    public void run() {
        for(String[] s : this.targetsAndReplacements) {
            this.text = performReplace(text, s);
        }
        myCallback.sucess(text);

    }

}
```

Declare this out of the next method:

```
int finishedThreads = 0;
ArrayList<String> resultsThreads = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Do this:

```
public void callMeWhenAThreadFinished(String result){
     finishedThreads++;
     resultsThreads.add(result);         

     if(finishedThreads==2){
           //do what you want to do with the results
     }
}
```

and this:

```
//...

Runnable r1 = new ParallelReplacer(someText, targetsAndReplacements.subList(0, targetsAndReplacements.size() / 2),new IMyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSucess(String result) {
            callMeWhenAThreadFinished(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
new Thread(r1).start(); //You forgot this 

Runnable r2 = new ParallelReplacer(someText, targetsAndReplacements.subList(targetsAndReplacements.size() / 2, targetsAndReplacements.size()),new IMyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSucess(String result) {
            callMeWhenAThreadFinished(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });
new Thread(r2).start();
```

Hugs

Answer (score 0):

While this may be helpful for starting to learn about multithreading, it's not useful for string processing. As stated in the comments, it's not gonna be conducive to merging the string later (at least in its current form).

The answer to your question is that **Runnable** provides a way to run functionality in a separate thread. But it *doesn't provide* the background thread itself.

In order to have it work in separate threads, you'd need to do something like this:

```
Thread first = new Thread(new ParallelReplacer(text, tars.subList(0, tars.size() / 2)));
Thread second = new Thread(new ParallelReplacer(text, tars.subList(tars.size() / 2, tars.size())));
```

Then you need to use the `Thread.join` API to wait for completion of the background threads in order to get the results. Or `Object.notify` in the threaded code, with `Object.wait` in the code that needs it.

I'm guessing that this is a homework question, so I won't go further here. But please do note that writing multithreaded code is nontrivial, and hard to get right even for very experienced developers. If this isn't just homework, you'll do far better using a proven library to help accomplish your work.

Answer (score 0):

the fundamental problem with your code is that it never uses any threads.

a Runnable in java is just a class that's garunteed to have a void method `run` that takes no arguments, so you're just calling it as you would any other function

**Starting the Threads**
to use threading, java has it's own class, `Thread`,
where thread is expecting a class that implements runnable, so you can do

```
ParallelReplacer[] replacers=new ParallelReplacer[{number of threads}];
Thread[] threads=new Thread[{number of threads}];
for(int i=0;i<threads.length;i++){
    replacers[i]=new ParallelReplacer(...);
    threads[i]=new Thread(replacers[i]);
}
```

this makes an array of `Thread` objects, ready to go with the replacer they're supposed to run, but it doesn't start them yet. To spawn the thread you call .start() on that thread, beginning it's execution, separately from the main thread, which continues running.

so you would do

```
for(int i=0;i<threads.length;i++){
    thread[i].start();
}
```

or just start each one after you create it in the previous loop

**Output**
the main thread of execution runs separately, and will run the next couple of commands before the ones you spawned finish execution, (even if the next command is return!), so you need to at some point tell your main to wait for all the spawned threads to finish

you can do this by calling `join()` on each spawned thread

```
for(int i=0;i<threads.length;i++){
    threads[i].join();
}
```

what join does is it tells the currently executing thread (ie main in this case) to wait until the thread it's called on to finish. because of this, it has to be done in a separate loop, other wise you would just have
start thread 1,
stop thread 1
start thread 2
...
and might as well not use threads at all

after all the threads are joined, you can loop through the replacers array, and append all the results.

**however**
you can do better! all the threads share the same heap, which is where java allocates it's objects. if you change your input string (which is immutable) to a `StringBuilder` (which can be changed in place), then you could have each thread change it's section, and when they are all joined, the StringBuilder would be all replaced.